# How To Use LDAP Authentication Information In Rails devise_ldap_authenticatable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ldap

Here is the configuration from devise_ldap_authenticatable document:

Edit config/ldap.yml and set our access details:

```
# [...]
development:
  host: ldap.phys.ethz.ch
  port: 389
  attribute: uid
  base: o=ethz,c=ch
# [...]
Generate the devise views:
.....................
```

And here is the information I can get, it is in Brats（I don't konw what it is) tool setting, it is about our LDAP server specific information:

```
"ldap_root_dn": "changedItAbcXCwgRHVjLE9VPUVuZ2luZWVyaW5nLE9VPUNBIFNhbnRhIENsYXJhIERELE9VPVVTIFVzZXJzLERDPWNvcnAsREM9ZW1jLERDPWNvbQ==",
"ldap_root_pwd": "rootPwd",
"ldap_server": "appauth.corp.company.com",
"ldap_port": "389",
"ldap_base_dn": "DC=corp,DC=company,DC=com",
```

I can find the **"host", "port"** is one-one corresponding relationship in devise_ldap_authenticatable and Brats. In my understanding, **"DC"** should be put to **"base:"** in rails (devise_ldap_authenticatable).

But where should i put the "ldap_root_dn", "ldap_root_pwd"? What is the corresponding part in rails. I guess "ldap_root_dn" should be put to "base:" as "DN=", or "DC="? I am not sure.

Could anybody can help me about this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for some people meet the same question.

1. In ldap.yml

attribute: sAMAccountName

........

admin_user: your correct root dn

admin_password: you correct pw

2 In devise.rb

config.ldap_use_admin_to_bind = true

After that every thing works fine, and logic is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Please read devise_ldap_authenticatable documentation, and follow this [screencast](http://corrupt.net/2010/07/05/LDAP-Authentication-With-Devise/).

I think you can add in ldap.yml additional entries for your credentials such as admin_user and admin_password.

[image]

Comment: I followed link http://wiki.phys.ethz.ch/readme/devise_with_ldap_for_authentication_in_rails_3 and video. It is always failed. The log showed:DAP: LDAP search for login: cn=myusername
  LDAP: LDAP search yielded 0 matches I think the request is sent and ldap server have received and processed it. But result is failed, is it right?

Comment: If my answers give you some help, can you please vote it ip ? 
If you can not see some error message, then it should be good I guess.